# encoding URL JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, encoding

I have another question, how do I find a way to encode the following characters - "**34ТФ**" (yes, it is Russian) in this code - 34%D2%D4

The problem is that if you use a regular "**encodeURI**", then you should get it - 34%D0%A2%D0%A4

P.S. I need it to produce the correct URL to a page on another site

Comment: You must make yourself clear on the subject if you want to encode or you want to encrypt.

Comment: @Andries I need out of it "34ТФ" - to get it "34%D2%D4". Sorry for my english, I'm just learning))

Comment: Do you know what encoding the other site is using?

Comment: What is your problem with `34%D0%A2%D0%A4`? It correctly decodes to `34ТФ` while `decodeURIComponent('34%D2%D4')` throws this error:
`URIError: URI malformed`

Comment: @Matt Unfortunately no. If anything, here's a site - [link](http://www.mosgortrans.org/pass3/), can you tell me?

Comment: @Stephan Bönnemann That's the problem! I know it's right, but to go to a page, it is necessary to go on such a link - '34%D2%D4'. So I wanted to ask - can we have any other methods of encoding?

Comment: I can't find anything on that page that leads to url with the string in it. Unless you find out the mechanism there's nothing we can do. Maybe ask the site owner or look through the Javascript/Html on the site to see if there's any indication of the encoding being used.

Comment: In any case, there's no way you can tell JavaScript to encode in any way other than the way it already knows.

Comment: @Matt Here is a link containing this line - [link](http://www.mosgortrans.org/pass3/shedule.php?type=avto&way=34%D2%D4&date=1111100&direction=AB&waypoint=0). Site administrator, I tried to contact

Comment: @Pointy sorry, but thanks anyway!

Comment: @IlyaKharlamov Did you get that link from a redirect from the server or did you go to it directly from the previous page? If it's the latter you can just look at the code on that page.